# Decoding a canvas todataURL

Tags: php, javascript, canvas

I'm having difficulty using data created with canvas's todataurl() method. Currently my code sends the resulting data to my php server which uses the file_put_contents() method to create a file to store that data. Now if I cut and paste the resulting gibberish from the file into an image tag src it works fine and displays properly so I assume so far everything is peachy.

But I keep running into issues when I try to use the code in JS. I've tried php's base64_decode method but kept getting currupt files. I found this code:

```
<?php
  $encodedData = str_replace(' ','+',$encodedData);
  $decocedData = base64_decode($encodedData);
```

and still got currupted files. Ideally I'd like to create a .png file with it but I'd settle for just processing the data file again in JS. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You simply have to read the MIME type (probably fixed/known) and the encoding (probably none) to interpret the data, which is standard Base64. There won’t be any spaces to be replaced if you URL-encoded the input earlier. [PHP-FileUpload](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-FileUpload) has a [`DataUriUpload`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-FileUpload/blob/023f812226673ac9e0696d8a3579bb7380606dda/src/DataUriUpload.php) component which does all this automatically. It’s documented [here](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-FileUpload/tree/023f812226673ac9e0696d8a3579bb7380606dda#data-uri-uploads).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems you have to get rid of the header that is prepended to the image data by the `toDataURL()` function.
On the client side you can strip off the header like this:

```
..
var data=canvas.toDataURL();
var output=data.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
// now send "output" to the server
..
```

On the server side use this:

```
<?php
    $decocedData = base64_decode($encodedData);
?>
```

Comment: That was helpful, here is what I ended up doing if anyone needs to do the same in the future: $backGround = substr($backGround, 22);
 $backGround = str_replace(' ','+',$backGround);
 $backGround = base64_decode($backGround);
 file_put_contents("currentBG1.png", $backGround);

Comment: need to add  jpeg to the regular expression as well: var output=data.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg|jpeg);base64,/, "");

Answer (score 3):

In java script send the result from canvas.toDataURL() on those browsers than support this method with the default type of "image/png".

```
var imageInfo = canvas.toDataURL();
// now send "imageInfo" to the server
```

Direct way to create the png file:

```
<?php
$imageInfo = imageInfoFromBrowser(); // Your method to get the data
$image = fopen($imageInfo, 'r');
file_put_contents("fileName.png", $image);
fclose($image);
?>
```

I have this working in PHP 5.3 / Windows, for other version, please check.

Image data sample for testing on PHP.

```
$imageInfo = "data:image/png;base64,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"
```

Comment: If this fail for you, please post your PHP environment. Thanks.

Comment: canvas.toDataUrl()... what is this ?

Comment: `canvas.toDataUrl()` is used  for example on [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/). 
You can get your canvas via JavaScript `var imageInfo = document.getElementById("yourid").toDataURL();` or via JQuery `var imageInfo = $("#yourid").toDataURL();` 
This solution posted by @DanielDeLeón works like a charm. Thank you,

Comment: I think this should be higher. Seems like the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Another important note is you have to convert blanks into plusses. If you do not do that, the decoded data is corrupted:

```
$encodedData = str_replace(' ','+',$encodedData);
$decocedData = base64_decode($encodedData);
```

You can read more at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php

Answer (score 1):

Other solutions did not work for me.

This works:

```
//image sample
$baseFromJavascript = "data:image/png;base64,BBBFBfj42Pj4";

// remove the part that we don't need from the provided image and decode it
$data = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $baseFromJavascript));
```