# Highcharts export charts on client-side into pdf

Tags: javascript, pdf, highcharts, export

I am currently using Highcharts in my web app. I am generating PDF reports with the following technologies (*all client-side*):

- my web page is converted into a canvas by `html2canvas`
- this canvas is rendered into PDF using `JsPDF`

The problem is that my Highcharts cannot be included in the process, it shows me empty divs.

A solution I've been thinking about is to render the charts individually in JPEG and add them manually to the image before rendering it in PDF, or even include them in another page of my PDF. I cannot figure out how to render these graphs in the client because in the Highcharts API there is only an option for downloading JPEG/PNG reports or rendering it into a particular div, how could I get it directly in JS? Do you see another possibility?

Comment: Simply use canvg lib to translate SVG to canvas, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995177/render-highcharts-canvas-as-a-png-on-the-page

Comment: Try to change [scale](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.scale) or other options for exporting.