# How to get image of graph from highchart in web page only?

Tags: php, svg, highcharts

I am currently using `HighChart` for my project.

It's working fine, but i want that chart as output in the "`image format`".

Currently it is giving as in "div" & "svg" tag. I want user can able to save that in image format by right clicking -> "`save as image`".

I have do search so many for this thing. Please help me out from this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to show image on web page...I dont want to download

Answer (score 1):

you can use export options provided by highcharts

```
exporting:{
 enabled: true
}
```

here is the api link to it http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting

a working js fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/VM8K2/

Hope this will help you

Comment: exporting allows to download..i want to show image chart on web page for my android application

Comment: You would need to set up some pre-canned images of every possible chart you would ever want to show. Android can handle downloading the chart from the export button. How is downloading an image on click different than downloading image via right click (or long press)? Same functionality, only using export server is much much easier for you.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the answers here:

- [Render Highcharts canvas as a PNG on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995177/render-highcharts-canvas-as-a-png-on-the-page)

And perhaps here:

- [How to save an image of the chart on the server with highcharts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802528/how-to-save-an-image-of-the-chart-on-the-server-with-highcharts)