# Benchmarking HighCharts, D3 and Canvas plotting

Tags: canvas, svg, highcharts, benchmarking

We are trying to choose SVG (HighCharts, D3) or Canvas for our application. Plotting efficiency is critical for us. So I did a very simple benchmarking on the `rect` drawing. Please check:

- [HighCharts 1000 rectangles](http://jsfiddle.net/agongdai/jxpSk/1/)
- [D3 1000 rectangles](http://jsfiddle.net/agongdai/7Cr8c/1/)
- [Canvas 1000 rectangles](http://jsfiddle.net/agongdai/VcddN/1/)

It turns out that highcharts spends around 900ms to plot, D3 spends around 50ms~70ms, while Canvas spends ~1ms to plot (check `console.log`).

I expected SVG may be slower than Canvas. But I never expect the gap is so big. Even worse, if I change the iteration number to be 10000, Canvas finishes within 10ms, while SVG runs for around 28s!!! Our application would not have so many objects, but this performance is not acceptable if we want to scale up.

Did I do anything wrong? How to write a more efficient code for SVG? The SVG exporting feature is also important for us.

Comment: What connection does drawing 10000 rect elements have with drawing a plot (which you'd do with a single path element)?

Comment: Performance-wise, we're also finding that all the SVG elements in a chart can make DOM operations (reflow/repaint) on a page containing charts to be very, very slow, particularly on a dashboard page that combines many different charts. Whereas, canvas is one element per chart, no matter how complex the render, and changes inside a canvas don't even trigger browser reflow operations. There are clearly other advantages to using SVG, but we're finding that when the question is scale and overall UX performance after the initial plot, canvas is clearly preferable, by at least an order of magnitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should compare rendering the same object, not initialize full chart and use renderer. In this scenario you should use this solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/jxpSk/2/

```
$(function () {

        var startTime = $.now();
        var ren = new Highcharts.Renderer($('#container')[0],600,1000);

        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            ren.rect(i, i, 100, 100, 0).attr({
                fill: '#FF0000'
            }).add();
        }

        var endTime = $.now();
        console.log('Time: ' + (endTime - startTime));
    });
```

then will be more objective.

Comment: @Bochan, thanks. But I need the 'chart' object to add the tooltips. And why it is faster? But the timing is speeded to ~350ms, which is still much worse than D3. What is the reason?

Comment: You can get rid of jquery and try to use standlaone wrapper http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/58-highcharts-standalone-framework

Comment: Ok, but in highcharts you can try to not use it, at this moment it is our efficient and we still develop our products to achieve better performance. Second solution is try to use a render chart on canvas like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995177/render-highcharts-canvas-as-a-png-on-the-page

Comment: We did some profiling, and it turned out Highcharts calls two methods that are not necessary when creating simple rectangles. With the updated code the performance is about the same as D3: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/jxpSk/3/

Comment: @TorsteinHønsi. Thanks. Yeah, the newest HighCharts is faster. But could you please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067388/highcharts-performance-degrades-dramatically-with-chart-and-renderer-togethe?