# HighCharts performance degrades dramatically with 'chart' and 'renderer' together

Tags: performance, highcharts

I am trying to get some feelings on HighCharts performance. Compare these two codes:

- A: [1000 rectangles with `Renderer` object](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/jxpSk/3/) ~50ms
- B: [1000 rectangles with `Renderer` and `Chart` objects](http://jsfiddle.net/agongdai/jxpSk/6/) ~500ms

The timing difference is ~10x, which is quite wired.

I need the `chart.tooltip` to show tooltips. So I cannot simply use the code A. But why the performance is so different? How to write a better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done some digging in Highcharts and it turns out to be the handling of Z indices in the SVGElement.add method that slows it down. The solution is to add your own group, and add all the rectangles to that group. Then the performance is the same whether you add it inside or outside a chart.

```
    var ren = chart.renderer;        
    var g = ren.g().add();

    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        ren.rect(i, i, 100, 100, 0).attr({ fill: '#FF0000' }).add(g);
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/jxpSk/7/

Comment: @Torstein_Honsi, thanks, it is working. I am not sure whether there are other hidden performance issues in HighCharts, although it seems better encapsulated than D3, we may use D3 for our application.